# Laptop specification for heavy excel file

Tags: excel, configuration, specifications

I am working on 600 MB+ excel file with more than 8,00,000 rows data in each 10 sheets and extra multiple column of formula in each sheet. Now the excel has stopped responding and is not opening even if I do not touch it for 3 hours.

I can't replicate these long formulae in Access (Even Sporfire or Tableau wont have simplified formulae of excel). And would get more such excel requirement in the future(heavy calculation and large excel file)

So, need guidance to replace my laptop with the best specification that could handle my excel and increase the efficiency.

Current configuration is 8 GB Ram and i5- 6300U CPU @ 2.4 GHz

I think Mac can handle it but its completely different to work in excel in Mac, as shortcut and functionality will be very different (have to unlearn/relearn many stuff)

I heard i7 with 16 GB ram would suffice. But need guidance from somebody on this.

Kindly help!!

Comment: Which version of Excel are you running? 32-bit or 64-bit? 32-bit can only use up to 2gb of addressable memory whereas 64-bit is able to use up to 8 terabytes. See [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/3066990/memory-usage-in-the-32-bit-edition-of-excel-2013-and-2016) for some more information about the memory limits.

Comment: I am using 32 bit excel and my operating system is 64 bit

Comment: I have tried opening this file in my colleague system which has 64 bit excel, 64 bit operating system and 8 gb ram, still facing the same issue